# How can I create a Typescript interface for a function that returns an $http promise?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using this function:

```
function httpGetQuestion(q) {
    return $http({
        url: '/api/Question/GetByUId/' + q.questionUId + '/fetch',
        method: "GET"
    })
}
```

and also this:

```
test.getQuestion = function (q) {
    getQuestion(q);
}
```

the parameter q is of type IQuestion

How can I create an interface that represents these function? Note that the getQuestion function does not return anything but the httpGetQuestion returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could look like this:

```
module myModule
{
    export interface IQuestion { ... }

    export interface IMyService
    {
        httpGetQuestion(): ng.IHttpPromise<IQuestion>
        getQuestion() : void
    }
}
```

The `ng.IHttpPromise<T>` is a return type representing the `$http` promise